# zend framework 2 flow diagram

Tags: zend-framework2

i am trying to understand ZF2 flow but it's little hard without flow diagram like this one for ZF1:

http://tournasdimitrios1.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/zend-framework-sequence_flowchart.jpg
http://otroblogmas.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/zend-framework-flow-diagram.png

alternatively how can I logged my custom events that was dispatched in my app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a Cheat-Sheet available:

- [<del>German Version of ZF2 Cheat-Sheet</del>](http://zendframework2.de/cheat-sheet.html) (no longer available)
- [<del>English Version of ZF2 Cheat-Sheet</del>](http://zendframework2.de/en/cheat-sheet.html) (no longer available)
- [English Version of ZF2 Cheat-Sheet (Alternative Link)](http://okeowoaderemi.com/site/assets/files/1103/zf2-flowchart.jpg)

Please note that those are copyright protected and you may not use or redistribute them anywhere. You may only link to them.

Comment: @sam The link you have given for english version is not working,Kindly check it pls

Comment: @Vimalraj.S Can't change the fact that apparently the author has removed the english version of it's cheat-sheet.

Comment: I Needed to look at the English version of this and found it was available in this web archive http://web.archive.org/web/20131004012328/http://zendframework2.de/en/cheat-sheet.html Some of it is missing but between the German One and this it is pretty useful

Comment: English version: http://okeowoaderemi.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/zf2-flowchart.jpg